# Create Excel chart of blood sugar level over time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a .csv of my blood sugar levels over time from the GLUCOFACTS application. I've imported it into Excel 2013 with the intention of making a visual chart of my data to my doctor. Unfortunately I'm completely stumped as to how to make it.

I'd like to make a scatter graph where the vertical axis is the blood sugar level and the horizontal is the combination of the date and time. The times aren't spaced equally (9:39, 11:44, etc) and I don't want them spaced equally on the graph. I'd like the horizontal axis to be an hour per tick and the times would fall between or on the ticks.

Date and time and blood sugar are on separate columns.

I've google for examples I can't find any that aren't outdated. For extra difficulty I'm working with the French version of Excel.

How do I do this?

Comment: Just checking: do you have 3 total columns or 2?  Can you post a picture of the data as it sits in Excel (possibly replacing blood sugar with random data if that's an issue)? Excels charts are very friendly and plot nearly anything you give them.  Occasionally it doesn't work and a picture goes a long way.  This should be as simple as a normal `Scatter` with date/time on X and values on Y.  You can then change x-axis formatting to show hours.

Comment: Hi! Date, time and blood sugar are all on separate columns

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a new column that combines the date and time columns into a new datetime. Then use that new column as the x-axis and the graph should be correct.

How you do that depends on whether Excel has recognised the date and time columns as such or whether they are text.